# Cannot correctly declare variable in procedure loop

Tags: mysql, linux, centos6, declare

This is driving me bananas. I'm not a mysql guru by any stretch. My goal is to add a large number of columns to a table. I've tried this several ways and the procedure chokes on the DECLARE @FooA NVARCHAR(MAX);. No clue as to why.

I appreciate any pointers...

```
USE mydatabase;
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS RepeatLoopProc$$
CREATE PROCEDURE RepeatLoopProc()
BEGIN
   DECLARE x INT;
   DECLARE sn VARCHAR(30);
   DECLARE dr VARCHAR(48);
   DECLARE @FooA NVARCHAR(MAX);
   SET x = 0;
   WHILE (x <= 150) DO
     SET sn = CONCAT('drivesn_', x);
     SET dr = CONCAT('driveinf_', x);
     SET x = x + 1;
     SET @FooA = 'ALTER TABLE DRIVE_MASTER ADD ' + sn + ' VARCHAR(30), ADD ' + dr + ' VARCHAR(48)';
     EXEC sp_executesql @FooA;
   END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I do this I get:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@FooA NVARCHAR(MAX);
```

My forehead is getting flat from slamming it into my desk.

The ultimate goal is adding columns drivesn_0, driveinf_0, drivesn_1, driveinf_1, etc all the way out to drivesn_150 and driveinf_150. Type VARCHAR(30) and VARCHAR(48) for each respectively.

Comment: MySQL doesn't use `+` to concatenate strings, you have to use the `CONCAT()` function.

Comment: If you're adding a large number of similar columns to a table, you probably have a poorly designed schema. Repeated elements should be in rows, not columns.

Answer (score 1):

@variables are not DECLAREd and declared variables' identifiers do not start with @.

Also, ALTER statements typically recreate a table behind the scenes (equivalent to something like CREATE TABLE newversion... INSERT INTO newversion SELECT * FROM oldversion ... DROP TABLE oldversion ... RENAME newversion). So you'd be much better off building up a single ALTER statement within the loop, and executing it only once.

---

Example:

```
   ...
   SET @FooA = 'ALTER TABLE DRIVE_MASTER';
   SET x = 0;
   WHILE (x <= 150) DO
     SET sn = CONCAT('drivesn_', x);
     SET dr = CONCAT('driveinf_', x);
     SET @FooA = CONCAT(@FooA 
                       , CASE WHEN x != 0 THEN ', ' ELSE '' END
                       , 'ADD ', sn, ' VARCHAR(30), ADD ', dr, ' VARCHAR(48)'
                 );
     SET x = x + 1;
   END WHILE;
   EXEC sp_executesql @FooA;
   ...
```

... but what Barmar said in comments is good advice, you should probably just have another table, something like `DRIVE_MASTER_DETAILS(x int, sn VARCHAR(30), dr VARCHAR(48))`

Comment: That is what I *think* I am doing. Alter is only done once per loop, adding two columns at a time.

Comment: Yeah, no, I was saying only alter once at all; even doing two columns at a time, you'd still be recreating the table 151 times. On very large tables even once can be painfully long. See example I added for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I already have multiple tables. Basically I am using this to catalog drive serial numbers in hosts. Host can have up to 150 drives. Other tables contain network interface information (macaddrs, etc). All tied together by a common index value. For a system with 150 disk drives I cannot see another way other than 150 columns. Either that or I am missing a fundamental concept.